# How can I push to a git bundle

Tags: git, push, bundle

I'm just starting to use git for version control.  I'd like to keep a backup copy of my repository on a local fileserver.  After reading about the right way to backup a git repository, I decided to store the repository as a git bundle on the fileserver.

I can bundle my repository and copy the resulting bundle to the fileserver.  Check.  I also tried cloning and pulling from it.  Everything working well.  However, I'd like to push my local changes from time to time as well.   When I execute something like

```
git push bundlefile.git
```

I get the error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'bundlefile.git'
```

You can clone or pull from a bundle, but is it not possible to push to it?  I don't really want to create a bundle of my whole repository every time I want to back up.

Is this user error or are bundles not intended to be pushed to?

Comment: There is a great example of how to manipulate and incrementally update bundle files at the end of the `git bundle` man page.

Comment: This seems to be getting a little far afield with bundles and bare repos.  If you simply want to backup your git repo, just tar (or zip) up the .git directory and be done with it.  Maybe do a "git gc" first to reduce the size a little.  This isn't a hard problem and doesn't require complicated solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot push directly to a bundle file. A bundle file is a compressed representation of a repository, and to modify it would involve unbundling, pushing, and bundling again.

One way to do this is as you said, create a new bundle every time you want to make a backup.

Another way is to create a *bare* repository on the file server, and push to that. A bare repository is a repository without a working directory, which is essentially the contents of the `.git` directory from a normal clone. You can create a bare repository with `git init --bare`.

Comment: That is a good suggestion.  I would have preferred to have a single file, compressed, that works as my backup solution, but the ease of pushing is more important than those considerations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have write access to the remote fileserver, surely:

```
myrepo$ git init --bare //server/my/backup/folder/myrepo.git
myrepo$ git remote add backup  //server/my/backup/folder/myrepo.git
myrepo$ git push backup --mirror
```

I haven't tried this exactly, but in MSys I have done it with paths like /j/myFolder/myrport.git and

```
myrepo$ git push --set-upstream backup master
```

Then a restore is just a clone of that,

```
dev$ git clone //server/my/backupo/folder/myrepo.git
Cloning into myrepo...
dev$ cd myrepo
```

and you're back to pushing happily again.

Answer (score -6):

It sounds like you have a permissions issue on the file server. Make sure that your user/group has write permissions.